# Left-clicking links doesn't work in Codepen, but 'Open in New Tab' does

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I look in the Firefox Network tab, it looks like the GET request goes through, but the page is not getting an HTML response. I am using jQuery to add a list item that contains a logo, a name, and a link where the user needs to be directed if either the logo or the name is clicked. The code is located here: http://codepen.io/veronikabenkeser/pen/PqxYvb

Relevant JS code:

```
if (logo === null) {
        logo = '<img class = "brownI" src=   "http://i358.photobucket.com/albums/oo27/picturesqueworlds/rss_circle_webtreatsetc_zpsfouqr1gj.png" >';
      } else {
        logo = '<img src="' + logo + '">';
      }
      if (stream !== null) {
        streamingIcon = '<img class = "streamIcon" src= "http://i358.photobucket.com/albums/oo27/picturesqueworlds/button_green_play_zpsgnkih0jo.png" >';
        item = '<li>' + '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/' + streamer + '"' + '>' + logo + '</a>' + '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/' + streamer + '"' + '>' + name + '</a>' + streamingIcon + '</li>';
      } else {

        item = '<li>' +
          '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/' + streamer + '"' + '>' + logo + '</a>' + '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/' + streamer + '"' + '>' + name + '</a>' + '</li>';
      }
      $(".content ul").append(item);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the link doesn't work when you click on it is because the content is on a different domain from codepen.io and violates the `SAMEORIGIN` policy

> Refused to display 'http://www.twitch.tv/freecodecamp' in a frame
>   because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

One workaround is to add `target="_blank"` to your href

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNbBoM)

Comment: How are you able to see that error message? I am looking in the Firefox console, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: The error shows up in chrome. I'm not sure about Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegated event handler since the link was appended.

Something like:

```
$(".content").on('click','a',function(){
  var theSource = $(this).attr('href');
  window.open(theSource , '_blank');
});
```

Comment: How would I select the object to which I would add this handler though since I wouldn't want the user to be taken to the link if they click anything other than he logo or the name and my object would basically be the whole bundle of logo + name + green icon if they're streaming. If I try doing it with a "this" obj or assign my obj to a var , I don't think clicking on the image will take you to the link because the obj will be a bundle of things. Am I right?

Comment: I tested the code I provided and it worked for all the individual logos and links I clicked. That code is pointed to any anchor tag clicked that is located inside of the "content" class. The "this" that its referencing would only be the one anchor tag that was clicked.